# ArcGIS Flow Path Tracing to Fixed Distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, arcgis-pro, arc-hydro

I'm looking for ways to trace points downstream only to a certain distance from the original point. I want to find the path downstream from a point to 'X' miles.

I'm familiar with the Flow Path Tracing in Arc Hydro, Q alternatives, etc... but I am unfamiliar with how to limit the flow length downstream.

There are probably ways to build a custom model for something like this, but an existing tool might already exist to address this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool in ArcHydro called Split Line Based on Distance, that solved it. Thanks for the downvotes.